# Using Apache POI can I stop users copying formatting?

Tags: java, excel, validation, apache-poi

I have made an excel sheet which is generated by Java. The cells can only accept certain values, depending on data validation done against lists on a separate sheet.

This all works great, but if a user copies some values from another cell and pastes it into the cell it avoids validation... is there any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by setting data format for that cell.

```
style = wb.createCellStyle();
style.setDataFormat(wb.createDataFormat().getFormat("0.000%"));
```

which will percentage value.
For documentation goto: 
[Apache HSSF Doc](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFCellStyle.html#setDataFormat%28short%29)